# Objects in Functions

Tags: javascript

How do I use objects within a function? Is this even possible? For example,

```
function myFunction(x) {
    return document.getElementById(x) 
{
        html: function(y) {
            return document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = y
        }
    }
}
```

So if I have the code `myFunction("body").html("hi")` or `myFunction("body").html = "hi"` (both should work), the inner HTML of the element with id `body` will change to `hi`.

If objects are not the way to do it, what is? (I want both `myFunction("body").html("hi")` and `myFunction("body").html = "hi"` to work)

Thanks.

Hopefully, this is a bit more clear.

Comment: You need to make setters. Check https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_accessors.asp

Comment: I want it to be a property...

Comment: In that case you need to write a setter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Comment: I'm confused. I want it to be a property of a function?

Comment: [“What to do when someone answers” - Don't be a chameleon, don't be a vandal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332820/839601)

Answer (score 1):

You can have it like this with some get/set gymnastics. Not sure it worth spending effort though. IMHO you should better stick to one interface: either you use properties or methods.

```js
function myFunction(x) {
    return {
      get html() {
        return function(value) {
          return document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = value;
        }
      },
      
      set html(value) {
        return document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = value;      
      }
    
    }
}

myFunction('a').html('hi')
myFunction('b').html = 'hi'
```

```html
<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain (just a little) what the get and set do?

Comment: Here you go :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at that.

Comment: How about when there is no property? Like just myFunction('b')?

Comment: Do you want it to be `myFunction('b') = 'hi'`?

Comment: As in cases of properties I didn't set or get. Like myFunction('a/b').style.display?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your requirements. This is likely doable with some Proxy. But I'd say this might be too advanced :)

Comment: The entire purpose of this is to shorten .innerHTML to .html . But if I use the code provided by you, properties such as .style or .disabled or just without a property, etc... issue an error

Comment: With Proxy you can do almost any kinda of meta programming related to properties. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy But, but, but...

Comment: Basically I want to make a custom property to a function. Is that possible? Thanks.